# Remove white space around <object></object>

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I am doing a website for internet explorer. (don't judge!)

I noticed this white border around the content of the second frame..
[image]
Here is the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Web remote Desktop</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    if(!(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0)) { window.location = "./redir.html"; }
  </script>
</head>
  <frameset cols="200, *" onload="checkIfIE()" name="full">
   <frame src="nav.html" name="nav">
   <frame src="content.php" name="desktop" scrolling="no">
 </frameset>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    if(true || isset($_POST["todo"]))  {
      echo('<object
                todo="irrelevant"
                width="100%"
                height="100%">
            </object>');
    }
    else {
      #display start page
      include_once "default.php";
    }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I looked up different ways to fix this - 90% of them being "*add `margin`, `padding` and/ or `border="0"`*" - that all have helped nothing if added to any or all, `<frame>`, `<body>` or `<object>`.

What else can I do/ what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Are you using a CSS reset stylesheet?  They can reduce headaches both in browser layout behavior and cross browser consistency.

Comment: Maybe it's the parent element from your `content.php` page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely a margin issue somewhere; but it might be hard to find where exactly; it could be inside of one of your frames, or maybe not. Try using browser developer tools (F12) and use the Select Element tool to click into the innermost element in that content frame. Then, with the Styles tab open on the right, click on each element in the tree until you find one that has a margin or padding that is affecting the layout.

Comment: so what was the solution at the end?

Comment: Who cares? I'm more of a fishing teacher than one to push someone aside and spear-fish for them. Even a googler could solve similar problems the same way.

Comment: it seems that this is not the case... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following CSS rules into the `<head>` of the page:

```
<style type="text/css">    
    html, body, object { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
</style>
```

And see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any CSS/styling added?

Try this inside a .css file and adding it to your `<head>`:

```
html, frameset, frame {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
```